# python dictionary updating/appending values for a key as a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary that needs to create a key when the key first shows up and adds a value for it, later on, keeps updating the key with values by appending these values to the previous value(s), I am wondering how to do that.

```
outter_dict = defaultdict(dict)  
num_index = 100
outter_dict['A'].update({num_index: 1})
outter_dict['A'].update({num_index: 2})
```

`2` will replace `1` as the value for key `100` of the inner dict of `outter_dict`, but ideally, it should look like,

```
'A': {100:[1,2]}
```

UPDATE

```
outter_dict = defaultdict(list)
outter_dict['A'][1].append(2)
```

but I got

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

if I do

```
dict['A'][1] = list()
```

before assign any values to `1`, I got

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `collections.defaultdict`:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
num_index = 100
d[num_index].append(1)
d[num_index].append(2)
print(dict(d))
```

Output:

```
{100: [1, 2]}
```

Regarding your most recent edit, you want to use `defautldict(dict)` and `setdefault`:

```
outter_dict = defaultdict(dict)
outter_dict["A"].setdefault(1, []).append(2)
print(dict(outter_dict))
```

Output:

```
{'A': {1: [2]}}
```

Comment: How about when `d` is a `defaultdict(dict)`?

Comment: @daiyue `defaultdict(dict)` will allow you to initialize a dictionary before hand and not have to worry about checking if a certain key exists in the subdictionary before each addition of a new key-value pair.

Comment: I tried to use `defaultdict(list)` as a nested dict, see my OP, but I got `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @daiyue please see my recent edit.